# How does a variable speed moving walkway work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering

How can a travelator (i.e. a moving walkway) such as those used in airports be mechanically made to increase speed incrementally when travelling towards the middle and to decrease speed incrementally when travelling towards the end to shorten the travel time from point A to point B?

Here is a video of this kind of [fast moving walkway at an airport.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvfF4TeXz7U)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link kinda shows how they do it already. The links in the band can separate which means the belt can stretch at variable amounts along it's length.

So all you do is place multiple idler sprockets underneath the track but preload the track differently between each pair of sprockets. In other words, you stretch the track differently between pairs of sprockets.

[image]

Between sprockets A and B, and between sprockets C and D you want the linear motion of the links to be slower so you choose a more links per distance (i.e. you want the belt to be less stretched).

Between sprockets B and C you want the linear motion of the links to be faster so you choose fewer links per distance (i.e.you want the belt to be more stretched).

So the total linear motion of each links is the tangential velocity of the sprocket PLUS the motion of the link as the belt becomes more or less stretched.

The motion produced by the belt becoming more or less stretched is determined by the difference in stretch (difference in links per distance) at the transition points.

As far as calculating things goes, I think that the average linear speed of the belt all the way around would need to equal the tangential velocity of the sprocket (the drive sprocket specifically), but that does not mean that the linear velocity of the links can't speed up or slow down around. They just need to have that average speed. In that way, it is not unlike a constant-velocity joint where the average angular velocity between input and output is the same, but that doesn't mean the output can't speed up and slow down in different parts of its rotation even as the input angular velocity remains perfectly constant.

Answer (score 0):

The belt is a combination of plates together that are capable of sliding into and expanding out of each other through the comb blades.

Say the length of the stretched belt is $X$ time its contracted state.

Then the fast speed of the belt

$$V_{fast}=X\cdot V_{slow}$$

The belt is driven at this speed for most of its course. Near the beginning though, it will gradually expand from a slow speed to fast and near the end, it will contract to a slower speed.

To reach from the slow speed, $V_{slow}$ to the fast speed the first N plates (the speed transition length) need to stretch $\frac{X}{N}$ each one by one until at the end of the Nth plate it is expanded fully and is moving at the speed of $V_{Nth-plate}=X\cdot V_{slow}=V_{fast}$.